# How to set different Locales for one Laravel Application pointed to two different domains?

Tags: php, laravel, translation, laravel-7, appdomain

In my laravel application I have two languages, `English and French`.

there are two domains for my application

```
test.site for French language
test.live for English language
```

Now if a user access test.site, application need to be loaded in French

But, if a user access test.live, application need to be loaded in English

My application's locale is by default set to EN.

**Now my question is,**

How can I set different locales for different domains? OR

How to load English for one domain and French for the other using same laravel application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [set a locale](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization) with: `App::setLocale($locale);`

To get the domain or host, Laravel requests provide a `getHost()` method, which should return `test.site` or `test.live`.

If you want to do this for all or most of your routes, it's probably easiest to create a [custom middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware) and either register it globally or group the routes you want to apply it to (check the documentation for details about registering).

Your middleware could then look something like this:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $locale = $request->getHost() == 'test.site' ? 'fr' : 'en';
    App::setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```